# Powershell Compress-Archive comand delete after compresssion

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using the Compress-Archive command to zip the content of a folder and I need to delete the compressed files on the original folder afterwards. Is there an option on the command to do so ?

Comment: [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7), [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What boxdog said. Compressing the archive using Compress-Archive makes a different file name i.e compressedfoo.dir -> compressedfoo.zip. So You can just delete the original file using Remove-Item cmdlet and specifying the original filepath